# How to aggregate a column's dates into a list of dates per person with Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, aggregate

I have the following data, with each row per ID and DATE. A person with the same ID can occupy multiple rows, hence multiple dates. I want to aggregate it into one person (or ID) per row, and the dates will be aggregated into a list of date

From this

```
ID   DATE
1    2012-03-04
1    2013-04-15
1    2019-01-09
2    2013-04-09
2    2016-01-01
2    2018-05-09
```

To this

```
ID   DATE
1    [2012-03-04, 2013-04-15, 2019-01-09]
2    [2013-04-09, 2016-01-01, 2018-05-09]
```

Here is my attempt

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'DATE'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
df = df[['ID', 'DATE']]
df_pivot = df.groupby('ID').aggregate(lambda tdf: tdf.unique().tolist())
df_pivot = pd.DataFrame(df_pivot.to_records())
```

The problem is it returns something like this

```
ID   DATE
1    [1375228800000000000, 1411948800000000000, 1484524800000000000]
2    [1524528000000000000, 1529539200000000000, 1529542200000000000]
```

What kind of date format is this? I can't seem to find the right function to convert it back to the typical date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need unique values in lists use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before aggregate `list`s:

```
df = (df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'DATE'], ascending=True)
        .drop_duplicates(['ID', 'DATE'])
        .groupby('ID')['DATE']
        .agg(list))
```

In your solution should working, but it is slow:

```
df_pivot = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].aggregate(lambda tdf: tdf.drop_duplicates().tolist())
```

> What kind of date format is this?

If is native datetimes, called also unix datetime in nanoseconds.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why your first solution works faster? Because you chain everything in one line?

Comment: @KubiK888 - No, reason is if use some custom functions per each groups, it is slow, because run for each group (and if more complicated function, more slowier). So better is run some functions per DataFrame and for group only simpliest function as possible. Not alwasy possible, but here yes - if remove duplicates per both columns + groupby + list is is same like `groupby` + unique list

Answer (score 2):

Many ways... agg preferred because apply can be very slow

```
df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].agg(list)

Or

df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.to_list())
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `groupby()` and `apply()` method:

```
result=df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].apply(list)
```

**OR**

```
result=df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].agg(list)
```

Now If you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
ID
1    [ 2012-03-04,  2013-04-15,  2019-01-09]
2    [ 2013-04-09,  2016-01-01,  2018-05-09]
Name: DATE, dtype: object
```

The above code is giving you `Series`,If you want `Dataframe` Then use:

```
result=df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].apply(list).reset_index()
```